# Why is SQLAlchemy producing an error when I try to execute a raw SQL-String with an percent sign in it?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I try to execute essentially some sql like this (which gets builded in a complicated way):

```
sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM entities WHERE (unit = '%')"
```

with this Python code:

```
engine.execute(sql)
```

What happens then is I get a

```
TypeError: 'dict' object does not support indexing
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: What database is backing your app?

Comment: If my answer below doesn't help, could you please include the *full* traceback to the exception please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but I think SQLAlchemy is trying to intepret the `%` character as a SQL parameter. I'd try doubling the `%` character to work around this:

```
sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM entities WHERE (unit = '%%')"
```

This depends on what database you are using; different database adapters use different parameter styles. The psycopg2 module, used for PostgreSQL database connections, for example uses the `%s` style and [documents that `%%` is the correct way](http://www.initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) to insert a `%` literal value into your SQL statements.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. I was trying to escape with \% and getting nowhere.